# Using large GVCF file for population genetics

Tags: r, vcf-variant-call-format

I am following a tutorial to calculate population genetics statistics in R from GENETIX (extension .gtx), STRUCTURE (.str or.stru), FSTAT (.dat) and Genepop (.gen) files format.
https://github.com/thibautjombart/adegenet

I start from a GVCF file, which has more than 1.5 millions rows.

I have tried different strategies to import my dataset in Genepop format.
The vcfgenind package is crashing on my computer, probably in reason of the very large VCF file.
The packages commands genomic_converter(), or read.vcf() failed to read all the file and incorrectly capture the INFO fields of the GVCF file.

I think I have missed a detail, as an intermediate conversion of the VCF to another format. Would anyone had a method for NGS analysis from GVCF file to population genetics?

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I'm a Hail maintainer.

GVCF files are a bit different from VCF files. GVCF files are a sparse representation of the entire sequence. They contain "reference blocks" which indicate genomic intervals in which the sample is inferred to have homozygous reference calls of a uniform quality.

In contrast, a typical "project" VCF (sometimes called "PVCF", often just "VCF") file *densely* represents one or more samples, but only at sites at which at least one sample has a non-reference call.

I am not familiar with the tools you've referenced. It's possible those tools do not support GVCF files.

You might find more success working with [Hail](https://hail.is). Hail is a Python library for working with sequences. It presents a GVCF or VCF to you as a Table or Matrix Table which are similar to Pandas data frames.

---

Do you have one GVCF file or many? I don't know how you can do population genetics with just one sample. If you have multiple GVCF files, I recommend looking at the Hail [Variant Dataset](https://hail.is/docs/0.2/vds/index.html#sec-vds) and [Variant Dataset Combiner](https://hail.is/docs/0.2/vds/hail.vds.combiner.VariantDatasetCombiner.html#hail.vds.combiner.VariantDatasetCombiner). You can combine one or more GVCF files like this:

```py
gvcfs = [
    'gs://bucket/sample_10123.g.vcf.bgz',
    'gs://bucket/sample_10124.g.vcf.bgz',
    'gs://bucket/sample_10125.g.vcf.bgz',
    'gs://bucket/sample_10126.g.vcf.bgz',
]

combiner = hl.vds.new_combiner(
    output_path='gs://bucket/dataset.vds',
    temp_path='gs://1-day-temp-bucket/',
    gvcf_paths=gvcfs,
    use_genome_default_intervals=True,
)

combiner.run()

vds = hl.read_vds('gs://bucket/dataset.vds')
```

If you only have a few thousand samples, I think it is easier to work with a "dense" (project-VCF-like) representation. You can produce this by running:

```
mt = vds.to_dense_mt()
```

From here, you might look at the [Hail GWAS tutorial](https://hail.is/docs/0.2/tutorials/01-genome-wide-association-study.html) if you want to associate genotypes to phenotypes.

For more traditional population genetics, the Martin Lab has shared [tutorials](https://github.com/atgu/hgdp_tgp/tree/master/tutorials) on how they analyzed the HGDP+1kg dataset.

---

If you're looking for something like the F statistic, you can compute that with Hail's [`hl.agg.inbreeding`](https://hail.is/docs/0.2/aggregators.html#hail.expr.aggregators.inbreeding) aggregator:

```py
mt = hl.variant_qc(mt)
mt = mt.annotate_cols(
    IB = hl.agg.inbreeding(mt.GT, mt.variant_qc.AF[1])
)
mt.IB.show()
```